# How do I set up relationships between items in different lists?

Tags: list, data, database-connection

I'm working on an application which tracks and stores employee certifications and education levels.

As it stands, I have one SP list for the general employee info (Hire date, years of professional experience, etc), one for education (Degree, School, Year) and one for certifications (Cert, year).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to create relationships between these data sets. So, for example, I can enter a record in the employee list then link it to multiple education entries or certification entries. For that same employee.

For example, employee A could have three different degrees, and id want those education list entries to be linked to their main employee list entry.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint, you can **establish a relationship** between list items in the first list and related items in the target list using a **lookup column**.

> **Note:** Although the SharePoint Lists works as a table, it's not a rational database management system.

In your case, create a new lookup column in the `general employee info` to get data from `certifications` list as shown below:

[image]

Once you configure your lookup column in the first list, and when you try to create a new item, you will be able to select multiple certificates for each employee as shown below:

[image]

---

> Check also **[Auto-Populate List Form Fields Based On Lookup Selection In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)**

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, Mohamed. I'll try this out and see where it leads me.

Comment: @Kretzge You're welcome!

Comment: Mohamad, is there any way to make the certifications from my second list more unique? For example, though I can now link the items to an employee using your solution, they are still listed under 'Certification Name'. If multiple employees have the same certification (each with different days of achievement and expiration dates), I won't know whose entry is whose. Is there any way to make the title more descriptive aside from naming it something like 'EmployeeACertification' ?

Comment: @Kretzge Yes, you can by renaming the title field in the lookup list!

Comment: @Kretzge Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helps!! and if you have additional questions please ask it separately as a new thread!